# Getting the Value of an innerHTML of a select tag with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have this select tag right here

```
<select id = "options" style = "width:150px;">      
    <option>Artist Name</option>
    <option>Track Name</option>
    <option>Date Uploaded</option>
</select>
```

I am getting the current selected innerHTML value using JQuery

```
   var option = $("#options").innerHTML;
   console.log(option);
```

But each time I print it only returns me a value of undefined.

Comment: Your code `$("#options").innerHTML`, though it doesn't work, implies you are trying to get the html of _all_ of the option elements at once. But your comment _"I am getting the current selected innerHTML value"_ sounds like you want to get the value property of the selected option element. Could you make your desired result a bit clearer? What value do you _want_ the `option` variable to have after that code runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need:

```js
  $("#options").val();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "options" style = "width:150px;">      
    <option>Artist Name</option>
    <option>Track Name</option>
    <option>Date Uploaded</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh shoot! I was doing $("#options").val . looks like it is returning the whole JQuery object value. lol

Comment: This wil return the value attribute instead of innerHTML, if it is set. Example: in this case `<option value="an">Artist Name</option>`, `$("#options").val()` will return "an" instead of "Artist Name"

Answer (score 14):

jQuery object doesn't have the `innerHTML` property, which belongs to the html dom element object.

```
var option = $("#options option:selected").html();
console.log(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<select id = "options" style = "width:150px;">      
    <option>Artist Name</option>
    <option>Track Name</option>
    <option>Date Uploaded</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="optionstext"/>
<input type="text" id="optionshtml"/>
</form>

    $('#options').change(function(){

        $('#optionstext').val($('#options').text());
        $('#optionshtml').val($('#options').html());

    });

http://jsfiddle.net/pKsC8/8/
```